# Disable of discrete/native graphics on MacBook Retina when using apps like VMware, VLC, etc

Tags: graphics-card, switching, macbook-pro-retina, discrete-graphics

I got a MacBook Pro Retina a few months ago and I'm really happy with it. However, since I do a lot of work in different environments/OSes, I make heavy use of VMware to have them with me when I'm on the road.

The MBPr has a great battery life - as long as integrated graphics are being used. Unfortunately as soon as I launch VMware, the MacBook switches to discrete graphics and battery life is effectively halved.

I noticed that after installing gfxCardStatus, and now I'm wondering if there is a way to force the integrated graphics being used all of the time, so I can enjoy maximum battery life.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think with gfxCardStatus you can force the macbook to use integrated all the time; That's what I'm doing at least, with the exact same program to boot. There should be an option available if you click on the gfxcardstatus icon.